# Rotating the hands of a round gauge/meter with touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, quartz-core

I have a round gauge-looking UIView that has a hand that rotates around the center anchor point (think: speedometer). I have it working so the hand rotates to the correct place given a value using a layer transform.

I would like the user to be able to drag and pull the hand of the meter to another value. I'm having trouble figuring out that interaction though- I can use a UIPanGestureRecognizer on the hand itself to get a translation point, but how do I calculate the adjusted hand angle from that? This is actually seems more of a geometry question than anything.

Also, because it is a round meter, I don't want to adjust the angle based on either just the x or just the y components of the translation point.

Comment: is the "needle" a view? or are you just drawing the "needle"?

Comment: The needle is a UIImageView. I have it pinned the center using the anchorPoint and rotating using CATransform3DMakeRotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right, this is simple geometry: converting between polar and cartesian coordinate systems. Use the location of the touch point to find the angle around the circle (as if it were in polar coordinates):

```
CGPoint touchPoint = ...;
double touchTheta = atanf(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
```

Then you can do something like calculate the endpoint of the needle, given its length (radius):

```
CGPoint needleEndpoint = (CGPoint){needleLength * sinf(touchTheta),
                                   needleLength * cosf(touchTheta)};
```